# Spring .Net Remoting Advantages

Tags: remoting, spring.net

I am developing remoting application.
Which one will be useful, dot net remoting using spring dlls or regular .net remoting using system.runtime.remoting

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Spring's .NET Remoting support allows you to export a 'plain CLR
>   object' as a .NET Remoted object. By "plain CLR object" we mean
>   classes that do not inherit from a specific infrastructure base class
>   such as MarshalByRefObject.

Supports DI and AOP on service endpoints.